# Offset not working in bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi offset is not working in bootstrap 4 for the following code..trying in both i.e and chorme ..please tell me if anything is wrong in my syntax

```
</head>
<title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="saple.css">

</head>
     body>
      <div class="container-fluid" >
       <h1 id="hello">AURORA</h1>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-4 offset-xs-4 col-sm-4 offset-sm-4 col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 col-xl-4 offset-xl-4" id="sub">Menu</div>
           <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">sub menu</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The correct syntax in Bootstrap 3 is `.col-{size}-offset-{amount}` (e.g. `.col-sm-offset-3`).
2. `xl` doesn't exist in Bootstrap 3. This is a Bootstrap 4 thing.

If you're using Bootstrap 4, `.offset-{size}-{amount}` is the correct syntax (meaning your `.offset-md-2` etc. are valid classes).

Make sure you're including the correct version of Bootstrap on your page.

Comment: i have tried with bootstrap4 but don't know what's missing i am not seeing any bootstrap action..please see i have updated the code after giving it a shot according to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In my case on RoRails using bootstrap 3, i had to use this way

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
</div>
```